# Проверка наличия рукописного текста (подписи) на изображении (скан документа)

Tags: php, распознавание-символов

К сожалению, в поисках информации зашёл в тупик.

Есть задача:

Необходимо проверить отсканированный документ (УПД) на наличие подписи (рукописной). Цвет подписи может быть любой (ну скорее всего в синих или черных оттенках).

Есть некоторые мысли:

Я нашёл закономерность. Подпись располагается прямо под текстом, который я могу распознать. Следовательно я могу вычислить координаты этого текста и проверить наличие подписи в заданной области под этим текстом.

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать? Возможна реализация этого на PHP? Возможно посоветуете какую-то библиотеку?

Comment: @ssv32, спасибо за идею. Возможно посоветуете инструмент, с помощью которого это можно реализовать?

Comment: примерное решение. Берёте область где должна быть подпись, часть картинки снизу (заданного вами размера , количества пикселей). imageCreateFromJpeg , imagecolorat просматриваете цвета пикселей в этой  области, если количество цветных пикселей больше чем у картинки без подписи то подпись есть. Можно задать погрешность какую то на искажение. Будет лучше если вы высылаете документ и вам известно какой он. Может есть решение и поумнее конечно.

Comment: @ssv32 спасибо. Выглядит всё просто и надёжно. С вашего позволения, я немного подожду других вариантов. И если не будет какой-то более изящной гипотезы, то я ваш ответ отмечу.